# Regex for verifying content between tags in XML

Tags: java, xml, regex

I am trying to use regex for verifying contents in an XML file. I have tried the following things.

XML file 1:

```
<start>
   <hi>2dsds</hi>   
   <expected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123</expected>        
   <bye>2dsds</bye>
```

XML file 2:

```
<start>
   <hi>2dsds</hi>   
   <Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123</Somethingexpected>
   <bye>2dsds</bye>
```

In these two XML files, I am concerned about the contents between the fields `<expected>` and `<Somethingexpected>`. I want each and every field between that content to be numeric.

Valid contents:

```
<Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123</Somethingexpected>
<Expected xmlns=\"\">123</Expected>
<expected xmlns=\"\">123</expected>
```

Invalid contents:

```
<Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123a</Somethingexpected>
<Expected xmlns=\"\">avbv 123</Expected>
<expected xmlns=\"\">**(***</expected>
```

I don't need anything other that a number between the tags (not even a space)

I have tried using these regular expressions:

```
    if(String.matches(".*<.*[eE]xpected.*?>.*[a-zA-Z].*<.*") || 
       String.matches(".*<.*[eE]xpected.*?>.*[^0-9].*<.*"))    
        return invalid;
    else
        return valid;
```

Input 1:

```
<Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123</Somethingexpected>
```

Input 2:

```
<start>      
    <hi>2dsds</hi>
    <Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123</Somethingexpected>
    <bye>2dsds</bye>
```

For input 1, this says *valid*. For input 2 it says *invalid*

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Could anyone correct my regexes?

Comment: For one, you're using a regex against raw XML. Use XPath to extract the value first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
boolean mathes = str.matches(".*<(Expected|expected|Somethingexpected).*?>\\d+</\\1>.*");
```

Comment: Awesome buddy .. It worked .. I have also improvised the same like the below .. I am not specific about somethingExpected .. It could be even NothingExpected (i.e anything preceded by expected) like this ".*<(.*[Nn]odeId).*?>\\d+</\\1>.*" .. Now it works .. Just curious to know what does that \\1 mean .. Thank you ..

Comment: this means "what group 1 matched". group 1 is what's in (). that is for <Expected ..  there must be </Expected>

Comment: <Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123</Somethingexpected>  <Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123a</Somethingexpected>

In cases like this, I expect the result should fail as there is 123a between one of the tags. But the test passes as it finds the first one to be valid as it has 123 between..


Hence I was wondering whether shoudn't I be using regex at all in this case or is there an alternative for this .. Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123</Somethingexpected> <Somethingexpected xmlns="sw2223" xmlns=\"\">123a</Somethingexpected>
```

In cases like this, I expect the result should fail as there is 123a between one of the tags. But the test passes as it finds the first one to be valid as it has 123 between.. Hence I was wondering whether shoudn't I be using regex at all in this case or is there an alternative for this .. Thanks